# Why does my object not alert when I've made it, saved it, and want to alert it?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm making a code where the user enters information and it stores it in an object, but when I check if the object is saved by alerting one of its values it says there is no such object.
here is my code.

```js
let users = {};

function user(name,real){
  this.username = name,
  this.realname = real,
  this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() *1000);
  this.subs = 0,
  this.videos = [],
  this.listuser = function() {
    return this.username;
  }
};
function newuser(name, email,username){
  users[name] = new user(username, name);
};


let savefile = () => {
        
  var channame = string(document.getElementById('channame'));
  var name = string(document.getElementById('name'));
  var email = string(document.getElementById('email'));
  newuser(name,email,channame);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>youtube ripoff</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <br> <br><br><br><br><br>
  <form action="">
  <label for="username">Channel Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="channame" name="channelname"><br>
  Real Name
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
  Email
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onmousedown="newuser('name1','name@gmail.com','channelname1');">
  <br><br><br><br>
  
  <input type="button" value="Load Channels" id="seech" name="seechannels" onmousedown="alert(users['name1'].listuser());"><br>
  </form>
    <script src="script.js">
    function fun(){
      window.alert("starting program...")
      //other code
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there some sort of error that I'm not seeing?

Comment: When you use `<script src="`…`">`, its content will be ignored. See [What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](/q/6528325/4642212). Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: The `this` inside the `listuser` function isn't what you think it is. Probably undefined as it is called from mousedown handler.

Answer (score 1):

After click on submit button in form with action="" page is reload and all data is lost. Pleas use:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
```

instead of

```
<form action="">
```

This prevent page reload.